# задать цвет кнопки javafx

Tags: javafx

В цикле создаётся n-ое количество кнопок.
Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на копку,
она окрашивалась в зелёный цвет.
Так не получилось:

```
package javaapplication32;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaApplication32 extends Application {
    private final VBox vbox = new VBox(30);

    private final List<Button> list = new ArrayList<>();
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(30));

        createButton();

        addEvents();

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void createButton() {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Button btn = new Button("Кнопка " + i);

            list.add(btn);

            vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn);
        }
    }

    private void addEvents() {

        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {

            list.get(i).setOnAction(e -> {

               list.get(i).setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");  // здесь проблема
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправь метод на

```
private void addEvents() {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int finalI = i;
    list.get(i).setOnAction(e - > {
      list.get(finalI).setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Всё работает

Comment: Можно без создания финальной переменной 
    list.get(i).setOnAction(e - > {
  ((Button) e.getSource()).setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
 });

Comment: Спасибо тоже хороший вариант